# Questions filter with 2 specific tags not working correctly

Tags: bug, tags

Why am I getting questions tagged with `java` while I've selected `javascript` and `arrays`?

[image]

If I remove and just add `[javascript][arrays]` in search field then still I get the questions tagged with either `java` or with `array` tag with one or more tags (`javascript` seems optional)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps OP initially included the Javascript tag, and removed it during the grace period, *after* the Javascript question had been sent to your browser via the websocket, but before you clicked on the question to load it? That's my guess

Comment: This is because it matched the word "and" perhaps? To search for both tags just use [javascript][arrays] no operator required

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Thought abut that, but if that were the case, wouldn't the question have [shown up here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20and%20%5barrays%5d)? (unless it's a caching thing, but even so, there aren't any posts there which just contain "and" but aren't JS/arrays related)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 If I do so then I get questions which are tagged with `arrays` while addition of `javascript` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is correct - you have a custom filter on `javascript`, however if somebody posts a question tagged `javascript` `java` (which is VERY common) and an edit removes the `javascript` (again VERY common on account on happening so often) then [for a little while the question would act as if it still had the `javascript` tag](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: I can't find the question to verify this, though. It's probably deleted and I don't feel like doing a SEDE query. Can you provide a link? You can also check the edit history and see if an edit was made very early on to remove/change a tag.

Comment: @VLAZ https://stackoverflow.com/q/61136993 OP says he didn't add the Javascript tag and then remove it during the grace period (it's not in the edit history either)

Comment: OK. I don't know why I couldn't find it - I tried the title and sorted by newest. I must have mistyped something. Anyway, you're right - there doesn't appear to be an edit on tags - I'd expect one to come from another user not the OP (that's what usually happens). Maybe it is a bug. Let me try it with a custom filter.

Comment: OK, doesn't show in a custom filter *now* but that doesn't really prove anything. I'd still blame caching but I'm not sure what the reason for mus-categorising it in the first place is.